# Ubuntu software centre get dissapeared

Tags: 14.04

i am having ubuntu 14.04 LTS . my ubuntu software centre get deleted from my computer. when i write command 'sudo apt-get install in terminal' it shows unable to loacate package . i am new to ubuntu please help me.

Comment: The Ubuntu Software Center was replaced by the new Ubuntu Software (based on Gnome Software). If you are noticing it NOW you had long overdue updates.

Comment: @MichaelBay my system is up to date.ubuntu software is also missing .